# How to disable a library dependency at compile time using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Pretty sure this is a common use case but I'm not able to find a modern, simple approach for it:

I want to have optional libraries / code parts in a library which I'm working on. I use cmake and C++17. What I'm trying to achieve is for example to disable a logger library at compile time (e.g. to reduce dependencies).

The simplest way I know about is to pass a cmake flag and use it with the preprocessor.  But with this approach I'll end up in a preprocessor hell when I have more than one optional lib.

Comment: There are other ways you can add optional libraries that does not need a lot of preprocessor involvement however I would say it depends on the use case.  One such way could involve a factory that an object  created by the factory does not get registered if the optional library is not present because the source file that does the registration is not compiled because its not added by CMake to the list of sources when the optional library is not present.

Comment: yep, `#ifdef`s galore is pretty much the way to go

Comment: :D ok, not exactly what I've wanted to hear. I suppose I'll go into the #ifdef hell...

Comment: One could devise a plugin architecture where every optional thing is a plugin that does nothing by default (i.e. unless replaced with a real thing). However in practice I have never seen it being done this way. It always seems to be a ton of `ifdef`s.

Comment: For the plugin idea you could have CMake not create a plugin for the optional thing when it's disabled. Then your plugin loader only loads and activates the plugins that exist. This of course is highly dependent on your program design. In the case of the log example the where a log has to exist because existing objects use it directly all the time the current answer is a good approach.

Comment: Where would be the benefit of the plug-in handler? I implemented the approach of the current answer with the "do nothing" classes today and it seems to be pretty clean. In my case cmake is implicit the plug-in handler. When I want to link again the actual class ( here the logger) I pass a flag with the cmake command, otherwise I link default to the dummy implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a case like this where one of the choices is basically "don't really do anything", it can be pretty easy to avoid the typical tangled mess of `#ifdef`s.

To do so, you create two libraries, one for the do-nothing logger, and one for the real logger. Then at the CMake level, you decide which of your libraries to link against. The real logger then links against the other library (e.g., glog), while the do-nothing version just contains functions with the right names, but all of them (obviously enough) do nothing--or in some cases, have something minimal like "return true;` to indicate success, even though they did nothing else.

Assuming you use an iostream-like interface to your logger, an implementation of the do-nothing logger may be just about this simple:

```cpp
#pragma once
// logger.hpp

enum { CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING };

class Logger {
public:
    Logger(int) {} // ignore logging level
};

template <class T>
inline Logger &operator<<(Logger &os, T const &) {
    return os;
}

inline Logger &LOG(int) {
    static Logger log{0};

    return log;
}
```

Then the code that uses it does typical logging "stuff":

```cpp
#include <logger.hpp>

int main() {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Ignore this\n";
    LOG(WARNING) << "Ignore this too\n";
    LOG(CRITICAL) << "Yup, also ignored\n";
}
```

...and all of it does absolutely nothing. A halfway decent optimizing compiler can pretty easily recognize this as dead code, so it compiles down to nothing in the object code as well.

One last minor caveat: getting CMake to deal well with header-only libraries is kind of a pain. Offhand I don't recall *how*, but I have gotten it to deal with them though, so it can be done.

Comment: I really like that idea and actually I already played a bit around with this approach. The benefit is that the code stays readable but the disadvantage is the higher effort for generating the dummy class. I'll check if I'm able to transfer your example to my real world libs . Your example class is really nice implemented by the way!